# Small white strip appearing at the top of Full-Screen Modal window on Safari | Firefox | Brave

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am facing an issue while opening a Full-Screen Modal window on **Safari, Firefox and Brave** browser from an **iPhone 14 Pro, iPhone 11 and iPad.** Occasionally, a small white strip appears at the top of the screen, which seems to be the content underneath the modal window. This issue is not appearing all the time, but it appears occasionally.

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

**Full Code:** https://pastebin.com/HhCyLnCa

**Image:**

[image]

**Video:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLBZ6.jpg